Computing the equivalent transform of an SVG viewport
I'm trying to apply the process explained in this link :
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform
I will apply the theory on a very simple example, a circle


svg {  
    background-color: gray;  
}
 <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 100">  
    <circle r="50"  />  
 </svg>



I will therefore apply the process explained in the link below, the goal is then to apply the transformation and achieve the same result
8.2. Computing the equivalent transform of an SVG viewport
This process converts the min-x, min-y, width and height values of a viewBox attribute, the position and size of the element on which the viewBox attribute is defined, and the value of the preserveAspectRatio attribute on that element into a translation and a scale that is applied to content contained by the element.

Let vb-x, vb-y, vb-width, vb-height be the min-x, min-y, width and height values of the viewBox attribute respectively.
the values ​​of my example
vb-x = 0
vb-y = 0
vb-width = 50
vb-height = 100

Let e-x, e-y, e-width, e-height be the position and size of the element respectively.
I think these are the attributes of the circle element
e-x = 0
e-y = 0
e-width= 50
e-height = 50

Let align be the align value of preserveAspectRatio, or 'xMidYMid' if preserveAspectRatio is not defined.
I have not defined preserveAspectRatio
align = xMidYMid

Let meetOrSlice be the meetOrSlice value of preserveAspectRatio, or 'meet' if preserveAspectRatio is not defined or if meetOrSlice is missing from this value.
meetOrSlice = meet

Initialize scale-x to e-width/vb-width.
scale-x  = 50/50 = 1

Initialize scale-y to e-height/vb-height.
scale-y = 50/100 = 0.5

If align is not 'none' and meetOrSlice is 'meet', set the larger of scale-x and scale-y to the smaller.
scale-y = 1 (if I understood correctly)

Otherwise, if align is not 'none' and meetOrSlice is 'slice', set the smaller of scale-x and scale-y to the larger.
n/a

Initialize translate-x to e-x - (vb-x * scale-x).
translate-x = 0 - ( 0 * 1)

Initialize translate-y to e-y - (vb-y * scale-y)
translate-y = 0 - ( 0 * 1)

If align contains 'xMid', add (e-width - vb-width * scale-x) / 2 to translate-x.
translate-x +=  ( 50  - 50 * 1 ) /2
translate-x =  0

If align contains 'xMax', add (e-width - vb-width * scale-x) to translate-x.
n/a

If align contains 'yMid', add (e-height - vb-height * scale-y) / 2 to translate-y.
translate-y +=  ( 100  - 100 * 1 ) /2
translate-y =  0

If align contains 'yMax', add (e-height - vb-height * scale-y) to translate-y.
n/a


The transform applied to content contained by the element is given by  :
translate(translate-x, translate-y) scale(scale-x, scale-y) =
translate(0 0) scale(1 1)  (of course this is not going to work, but where did I go wrong?)


svg {
    background-color: gray;
}
<svg  
    width="100"  
    height="100"  
    transform="translate(0 0) scale(1 1)">  
    <circle r="50"  />  
</svg>



Alors voilà, if I understood correctly, I could replace the viewBox element with the transformation translate(0 0) scale(1 1)
obviously, it doesn't work...
where did I go wrong?
AUGUST 4 : UPDATED FROM ACCEPTED ANSWER OF errstrietzel
first : I read the first paragraph of the specification  too quickly:

This process converts the min-x, min-y, width and height values of a
viewBox attribute, the position and size of the element on which the
viewBox attribute is defined, and the value of the preserveAspectRatio
attribute on that element into a translation and a scale that is
applied to content contained by the element.

c'est-à-dire, you must put the transform attribute in the circle element and not in the svg element.
then, I miscalculated the components e-width & e-height (line 2) :

e-width= 100
e-height= 100

alors translate-x is modified :

translate-x = (e-width - 50 x 1 ) /2
translate-x = (100 - 50 ) / 2
translate-x = 25



svg {  
    background-color: gray;  
}
<svg
    width="100"  
    height="100"  
    >  
    <circle r="50" transform="translate(25 0) scale(1 1)" />  
</svg>

<h1>equivalent</h1>
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 100">  
    <circle r="50"  />  
 </svg>




Frankly, I'm not sure I understood you approach but you can't really replace the viewBox attribute. The closest thing to a viewBox replacement would be specific width and height attributes or style properties when there is no viewBox specified. Transformations wouldn't even change the box size of an HTML element (actually the main benefit of transforms - we resize without layout shifts). In case of SVG keep in mind there are no auto-resizing capabilities (like e.g flex or grid) based on its content.

@herrstrietzel   it seems to me that it's not me who is trying "Computing the equivalent transform of an SVG viewport". (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform). What I am trying to do is to apply an example in order to understand the 14 steps of the link, that is to say to understand precisely viewBox

In Step 13, you give "n/a" despite the align part containing "YMid". (Your case would give the trivial result, so it doesn't influence the outcome.) If you are really picky, you can now complain about the lower case of the y in "yMid" quoted in the spec, despite the grammar for preserveAspectRatio only defining the upper case.

@ccprog exact ! it's true that this syntax is particularly cumbersome

If your ultimate goal is to gain a deep understanding of certain SVG aspects like viewBox combined with preserveAspectRatio you may rather opt for "secondary" sources providing a way more comprehensible explanation (actually the W3C spec documentations can be ... not so great "infotainment-wise").
See for instance this elaborate post on CSS-tricks.com: »How to Scale SVG«
Fun fact: the recommended post is written by Amelia Bellamy-Royds who happens to be a member of the current W3C SVG working group.
viewBox and preserveAspectRatio
Significant for your first SVG example is that element size and viewBox don't match. In this case the default preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" will take effect by centering the SVG content within the elements bounding box.


svg {  
  outline: 1px solid gray; 
  display:block;
}
<h3>viewBox doesn't match element size – preserveAspectRatio settings apply</h3>
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 100">  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
    <circle r="50"/>  
 </svg>
<svg width="400" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 100">  
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
    <circle r="50"/>  
 </svg>


<h3>Explicit settings</h3>
 <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 100"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">  
     <rect x="0"  y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
      <circle cx="0" cy="0"r="50"/>  
 </svg>

<h3>Omit viewBox – replicating previous result</h3>
<svg  
    width="100"  
    height="100">  
    <circle r="50" transform="translate(25 0) scale(1)" />  
</svg>



In the above example I've added a <rect> element with a size of width/height = 100% to illustrate the "object-fit" behavior. This full-size rect adapts to the intrinsic viewBox but not to the parent SVG size.
To replicate the layout without a viewBox we need to adjust the position by applying a transform to an elements but not to the parent SVG.
Applying a transform to the outermost SVG will only transform/shift the element in the HTML layout context but not inherit to inner SVG (child) elements.
Suggest clarifications for the official specs
You can also suggest improvements to the current spec descriptions via the github repo "w3c/svgwg"
Spec state: Is the specification implemented?
Keep in mind you're referring to a W3C SVG editor's draft (see the red background color on the left) – some described specs may not be implemented by any browser vendor to this date (or may be moved/removed to/from the next spec version ... or renamed ... I'm referring to the looooong history of text SVG line-wrapping concepts).
Also worth reading

Sara Soueidan "Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations (Part 1) — The viewport, viewBox, and preserveAspectRatio"


in fact, I had misplaced the transform attribute. What I find unfortunate is that the w3c site is missing examples. However, examples are fundamental!
